# Using php's array_search on an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php allows me to find the first array key based on an array value.

Can this be accomplished with a single PHP function if the value is nested in an object in the array values, or must it be manually performed as I show below?

Thank you

```
<?php
function getKeyBasedOnName($arr,$name)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$o) {
        if($o->name==$name) return $key;
    }
    return false;
}
$json='[
{
"name": "zero",
"data": [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
},
{
"name": "one",
"data": [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
},
{"name": "two",
"data": [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
}
]';
$arr=json_decode($json);
var_dump(getKeyBasedOnName($arr,'zero')); //Return 0  
var_dump(getKeyBasedOnName($arr,'one')); //Return 1  
var_dump(getKeyBasedOnName($arr,'two')); //Return 2
var_dump(getKeyBasedOnName($arr,'three')); //Return false
```

Comment: I believe your function is what needs to be done.  Beware if `name` is not set that will throw a notice.  Maybe revise your if to `if ( property_exists($o, 'name') && $o->name == $name) {...`

Comment: @cale_b  Thanks and point well taken.  Wasn't sure if there was some sort of walk/map version of `array_search()`.

Comment: Maybe `array_filter` could be used this way?  It'd end up being as verbose as what you've done, because to use an "outside value", you have do put it in a class and wrap it in a function.  As an aside, after working in Javascript / Angular more recently, and using the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library and finding it super useful, I often lament not having better tools like this. Have considered using [this library](http://anahkiasen.github.io/underscore-php/#Arrays-find) which ports many of those super-useful functions to php.

Comment: @cale_b.  Yea, maybe.  By the way, have you seen http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php?  Maybe what you are looking for.

Comment: There isn't a built in `array_usearch` function that allows you to supply a compare function. Wouldn't be hard to make one yourself.

Comment: Whatever method you use, if you only need the first value, you can `break` out of the loop after finding your value. You also don't need to `return false`.

Comment: @ldg  Guess I should know this but don't.  A function without a return always returns false?

Comment: @user1032531 returns `null`.

Comment: @ldg - note that OP actually returns out of the loop, which is prob more efficient than a break.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn  Just tested it, and found `null` as well.

Comment: it's true that the return will exit the function, `break` is just more readable and php style. I'm not sure if return is more efficient in this case, but I have to imagine it would be negligible. It's just a bit confusing the way it's set up in the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for fun, if the array is `0` based and sequential keys:

```
echo array_search('zero', array_column(json_decode($json, true), 'name'));
```

- Extract all the `name` key values into a single array
- Search for the name value to return the key

This decodes the JSON into an array.  You can decode it to an object after if you need that.  As of PHP 7 you can use an array of objects:

```
echo array_search('zero', array_column(json_decode($json), 'name'));
```

Comment: I guess this pretty much answers the question, but will likely keep with my simple function.  Thanks

Comment: No prob.  Added PHP 7 example.

Comment: I like the PHP 7 solution, and will try to remember it when I go to PHP 7.

Answer (score 6):

There's no single built-in function that provides for arbitrary comparison. You can, however, roll your own generic array search:

```
function array_usearch(array $array, callable $comparitor) {
    return array_filter(
        $array,
        function ($element) use ($comparitor) {
            if ($comparitor($element)) {
                return $element;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This has the benefit of returning an array of matches to the comparison function, rather than a single key which you later have to lookup. It also has performance O(n), which is ok.

Example:

```
array_usearch($arr, function ($o) { return $o->name != 'zero'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($json[array_search('zero', array_column(json_decode($json, true), 'name'))]->data);
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.